# I am creating a login system and I am having problems here

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mrcletus\index.php:14 stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mrcletus\index.php on line 14

Comment: How is this a C# question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a look on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also i agree with @panoskarajohn, you should remove the c# tags and add a php tag if your question is about php

Answer (score 1):

> Call to underfined function `mysql_query()`

You haven't enabled MySQL support in your build or installation of PHP. Check your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

Replace to mysql_query() to mysqli_query function